# Keywords of app in AppStore same as name of another app

Tags: ios, app-store, keyword

What might be the consequences if the keywords the application has the phrase as the name of another app in the AppStore?

And what if the developer of this app complain in the AppStore for my app?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about Apple's review policies and not about programming.

Comment: Why? I want to know the example is based on the experience of the developers. Who faced this situation and what it was

Comment: Even more off-topic since that would be primarily opinion based

Comment: You wanted to say, not the opinion and experience of the developer?

Comment: FYI.. this question wasn't at all opinionated and had a definite answer from Apple: "Choose a unique app name, assign keywords that accurately describe your app, and don’t try to pack any of your metadata with trademarked terms, popular app names, or other irrelevant phrases just to game the system. "  that is from https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/

Answer (score 2):

There are no restrictions, you are free to use any keywords as far as that fits into the following apple guideline:

> Developers are responsible for assigning appropriate keywords for
>   their Apps. Inappropriate keywords may be changed/deleted by Apple

To advertise my app, I used `HealthKit` as a keyword, it worked fine.

Reference: https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/